# Is it necessary to call SelectObject() before DeleteObject()?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I have an `HBITMAP` that is selected into a memory DC.

I know that I should call `DeleteObject()` on the `HBITMAP` before calling `DeleteDC()` on the memory DC, but is it necessary to also use `SelectObject()` to select the old `HBITMAP` into the memory DC (and hence selecting out the `HBITMAP` that I want to delete) before calling `DeleteObject()`?

Comment: From the `SelectObject` docs: *An application should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is necessary; two problems if you don't:

- the DC's original bitmap will be leaked
- the bitmap will be double-freed since the DC will try to delete it itself when it's destroyed

Comment: *the DC's original bitmap will be leaked* But what if I saved the DC's original bitmap and called `DeleteObject()` on it? *the bitmap will be double-freed since the DC will try to delete it itself when it's destroyed* So can't I just call `DeleteDC()` without calling `DeleteObject()`?

Comment: What's the point of that? This is a long established pattern for GDI objects, you really gain nothing by fighting it.

Comment: I will not do it the way I described it, I just want to know if it is technically correct.

Comment: Only the creator of the HDC knows how the original default object was allocated and how it needs to be destroyed. User code should not make any assumption about that. So you HAVE to select the original bitmap back into the HDC to ensure it gets freed correctly, and to also ensure that the HDC owner does not try to free your bitmap in an incompatible manner when it frees the HDC.  Whoever allocates a given object has to be the same one to free it.